# mysql prevent insert row auto sorting

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sorting, insert

I use Codeigniter to perform insert to mysql (not sure if relevant), I have table column and some data like this after I insert:

```
    [invoice_id][product_id][unit_cost][quantity]
    [42][1][50][2]
    [42][2][100][3]
    [42][5][45][1]
```

The problem is mysql auto sort it by invoice_id first then product_id like the above.

Before I insert them, my invoice item-list position was :

```
    [42][5][45][1]
    [42][1][50][2]
    [42][2][100][3]
```

I do not want any of this auto-sort because when I retrieve them, they went like the list in database not as in the invoice. I dont think I can use sort for a particular column because they are all random in the first place.

I can only start thinking to add another column [position] contain number just for the sake of sorting it later, or is there a better way without it?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Do you have any index on the table?

Answer (score 0):

You are not guaranteed the order of MySql resultsets unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause. The only way to do it if you cannot sort with the parameters you already have would be to add another column to the table. Typically this would be an autoincrement integer field. You would then be able to order by id, and return the rows in the order they were entered.

Comment: Every table you make should have a unique id field that auto-increments. But in this case, consider also having a 'time_created' field with a unix timestamp and have your query sort by the time the product was added to the invoice. The time things happen is often useful information to store, and also works well for sorting.

Comment: @AndrewR I guess I will add another column then.